# Deleting content from text field with Capybara

Tags: automation, capybara

I'm writing a script that fills out text fields with Capybara, but prior to filling out the fields, I want to ensure that the fields are empty and that text is not autofilled. Basically, I'm looking for the opposite of

```
(Object) fill_in(locator, options = {})    #empty_content_of? delete?
```

found here: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions. Advice?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After struggling with this, I asked a coworker and the solution was to use the following:

```
fill_in(locator, with: "")
```

So, for example:

```
fill_in "Name", with: ""
```

This makes perfect sense and is probably intuitive to many, but I was stumped and couldn't find an answer on SO so I thought I would post about it in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 28):

For me only this solution worked:

```
fill_in('Foo', with: 'bar', fill_options: { clear: :backspace })
```

I have Vue.js on frontend.

Comment: Me too. I'm using React.js on frontend

Comment: didn't even know this exists, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 16):

you can use the native selenium bindings to clear an input field without filling in an empty string

```
element = find('locator')
element.native.clear
```

I prefer this option rather than `fill_in`.

Also if you think about it fill in is limited to find your locator by label or name so if it doesn't have a label or name you still have to use `find`

Comment: using `fill_in field, with: ''` did not clear the field for me but his works.

Answer (score 9):

A solution that works for me and has always been reliable:

```
field = find('locator')
field.value.length.times { field.send_keys [:backspace] }
```

In Capybara terms of mimicking a user's behaviour, this also seems a correct way to me of doing that.

Comment: the only solution that worked >_>

Answer (score 5):

For React you've got to do more than that. `fill_in field, with: ''` does [`native.clear`](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/3.5.1/lib/capybara/selenium/node.rb#L209-L227). Which doesn't play nicely with React. As doesn't `fill_in field, with: 'some text'`. Since it does `arguments[0].value = ''` before typing text.

I've run into the issues with [`react-datetime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime). What I've settled with is:

```ruby
def fill_in_react_datetime n, options
  with = options[:with] == '' ? '' : format_date(options[:with])
  fill_in n, with: with, fill_options: {clear: [[:control, 'a'], :delete]}
end
```

Comment: This is what worked for me when trying to fill_in date fields in RailsAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the accepted answers, you can optionally pass `with: nil`:

e.g.

```
fill_in("search-input", with: nil, fill_options: { clear: :backspace })
```

I prefer`nil` over an empty string (`""`) simply for explicitness. I am explicitly *not* setting the value and clearing with backspace.  Makes for an understandable test.